Pine-Script's Security Limit Issue
How combine this pine script lines into a single  pine script with
TF5Bull   = securityNoRep1(syminfo.tickerid, "5"  , emaBull)
TF15Bull  = securityNoRep1(syminfo.tickerid, "15"  , emaBull)
TF30Bull  = securityNoRep1(syminfo.tickerid, "30"  , emaBull)
TF60Bull  = securityNoRep1(syminfo.tickerid, "60"  , emaBull)
TF240Bull = securityNoRep1(syminfo.tickerid, "240" , emaBull)
TFDBull   = securityNoRep1(syminfo.tickerid, "1440", emaBull)

and this
[monthly_time, monthly_open] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', [time, open], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
[monthlyh_time, monthlyh_open] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', [time[1], high[1]], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
[monthlyl_time, monthlyl_open] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', [time[1], low[1]], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

The combining result to reduce this error
Script requests too many securities: 60. The limit is 40

Please share you code you with a minimal reproducible example
